# Reshaping torch tensors of PIL images leads to multiple gray images of same image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, reshape

```
# creating a flower dataset
f_ds = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(data_path)
# a transform to convert images to tensors
to_tensor = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()


for idx, (img, label) in enumerate(f_ds):
    if idx == 2100:
        # random PIL image
        display(img)
        print(img.size, img.mode) # W * H

        # convert the same arrray to_tensor (a torchvision transform to convert images to pytorch tensor)
        img_tensor = to_tensor(img)
        print("After converting to torch tensor: ", img_tensor.shape)
        C, H, W = img_tensor.shape  
        
        # the same image reshaped to match matplotlib
        reshaped_img_tensor = img_tensor.reshape(H, W, C) # i think the problem is here...
        print('After reshaping img_tensor: ', reshaped_img_tensor.shape)
        new_arr = (reshaped_img_tensor.numpy()*255.0).astype(np.uint8)
        print("dtype:", new_arr.dtype, "min:", new_arr.min(), "max:",new_arr.max(), "shape:", new_arr.shape)
        display(new_arr, 'RGB')) 
        break
```

The same image array after reshaping is messed up.
Here instead of showing an image with 3 channels it shows gray image(1 channel) and 3*3 images somehow. What am I missing here?

Please help me solve this.

Thank you :D

[image: image displayed using pil]

Comment: Check the `dtype` of the array you pass to `Image.fromarray()`. Make sure it is `np.uint8`, i.e. `display(Image.fromarray(SOMETHING.astype(np.uint8)...`

Comment: This didn't work either, the image is completely black, When it is casted to integer all values are rounded to zeros

Comment: Ok, if your tensor has floating point values in range 0..1 you will need to multiply by 255 then round to np.uint8.

Comment: I tried that too. same black image

Comment: Ok, try inspecting your data! `print(YOURARRAY.shape, YOURARRAY.dtype, YOURARRAY.min(), YOURARRAY.max())` where `YOURARRAY` is whatever you pass to `Image.fromarray()`

Comment: I observed the values of tensors and I think the problem here is after reshaping them from torch tensors(C H W) to np arrays of (H W C). I think the reshape is messy.

Comment: You probably need to swap the axes so that the pixel axis is last: i.e., pixels stay together during a reshape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToTensor permutes the array and returns a tensor in the shape [C, H, W]. Using reshape to swap the order of dimensions is wrong and will interleave the image.

I should have used tenosor.permute to change the dimensions not reshape.

[Orginally answered in pytorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/to-tensor-transform-is-messing-my-images/155507/2?u=loki_k)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).